# Angular 7: Display fields dynamically

Tags: json, angular, rest

We are trying to build a search page in Angular 7 with Spring Rest API as backend. The search page has a drop down on the top. Based on the selection on the drop down, a set of search fields should be displayed. The details of the fields to be displayed are fetched from the DB using a rest service. Attached below is such a rest service response.

The fieldType drives the type of the field, i.e, text , drop down, calendar etc. How can we create a component in angular to display the fields based on this json response ?

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "collectionId": "letterCollection",
      "collectionName": "Letters",
      "fieldId": "LetterType",
      "fieldName": "Letter Type",
      "fieldLabel": "LetterType",
      "fieldType": "DROPDOWN",
      "placeHolder": "",
      "searchFieldSequence": "0"     
    },
    {
      "collectionId": "letterCollection",
      "collectionName": "Letters",
      "fieldId": "ProcessDate",
      "fieldName": "Process Date",
      "fieldLabel": "ProcessDate",
      "fieldType": "TEXT",
      "placeHolder": "YYYY/MM/DD",
      "searchFieldSequence": "1"     
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `*ngFor` and some `*ngIf`s if you are doing it template side. Alteranively you can do it backend too. There are many ways to skin this cat so you are going to have to do some more research and come up with an attempt. If you get stuck come back and ask a question with some concrete specifics on what is not working. As it stands now I am going to vote to close as too broad.

Comment: Can you provide some more background? Are you using TypeScript in addition? Would you consider using jQuery? What is exactly the REST response object scheme (what each WORD says)? You might want to use jQuery in order to loop over the content of the object. Use replaces and string operation, in combination with $.attr function and $.append/$.appendTo functions to add the formed html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assuming you are using TypeScript, do these steps:

Let's assume that the component files are `search.component.ts` - the component script and `search.component.html` - the component view (markup).

### 1. Create TypeScript class for one field object (one object in array):

I'd suggest you to create, if there's no one yet, the directory "class" in the client (angular) application root.
doesn't matter if you created or not, create a file named "searchInput.ts", and write the new `searchInput` class:

```
external class searchInput {
    collectionId: string,
    collectionName: string,
    fieldId: string,
    fieldName: string,
    fieldLabel: string,
    fieldType: string,
    placeHolder: string,
    searchFieldSequence: string
}
```

### 2. Import `searchInput` class to `search.component.ts` file, and Parse the REST API response as `searchInput[]`

In the Search typeScript file component, first, import the `searchInput`:

```
import { searchInput } from '../class/searchInput'
```

Replace the string after `from` in order to import the correct file (and class)

Also, add `searchInput[]` varriable to the the class `SearchComponent` (or any other class, for the `search` component) in this way:

```
export class SearchComponent {
    public fieldsToAdd: searchInput[]; //creating searchInput array.
    ...
}
```

Moreover, I'll assume you have the object `result` as the response of the server, and the next code lines should be executed **in** the success script:

```
   fieldsToAdd = result.json as searchInput[]; //if you're using JSON
   fieldsToAdd = result.json as searchInput[]; //if you're using any other method, but AFTER encoding.
```

This will "parse" the objects from the response to `searchInput[]` in the `public fieldsToAdd: searchInput[];` Mentioned before.

### 3. Last step: change `search.component.html` to parse and show the fields:

In whatever element you'd like to put the input in (can be `div`,`section`, just fit HTML markup rules), add:

```
<div *ngFor="let fieldToAdd in fieldsToAdd">
<label>{{FieldToAdd.fieldLabel}}</label>
    <input type="{{FieldToAdd.fieldType}}" name={{FieldToAdd.fieldName}} id={{FieldToAdd.fieldId}} placeholder="{{FieldToAdd.fieldType}}" />
</div>
```

the code above basically looping over the collection `FieldsToAdd` from the `searchComponent` class.
It adds, div, inside him label and input. if you have complex inputs like select, use `*ngif=""`. more at [this](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngif-else/0) article.

### Note:

I'd suggest you to change itemType to be like `<input type=""/>` value, so it'll make the code simpler.